# Matrix of a linear transformation that associates a matrix to its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the transformation $T: \mathbb{R^{2x2}} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^{2x2}}$, which associates, to each $A \in \mathbb{R^{2x2}}$, its transpose, that is, $T(A)=A^T$.

So, I know how to find the eigenvalues and eigenvalues of a matrix, but I'm confused about this question because I'm not sure how the matrix of $T$ looks like. 
This is what I thought:

if $$ A= \left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d \end{array}\right)$$
then $$T(A)=T\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d \end{array}\right)=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & c\\
b & d \end{array}\right)$$

Is $A^T=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & c\\
b & d \end{array}\right)$ the matrix of the transformation $T$?

Comment: No, that is not the matrix of transformation of $T$.  $A$ here is an element of the vector space that $T$ acts upon.

Comment: The eigenvectors of $T$ are precisely the matrices $A$ for which $A^T$ is a multiple of $A$.  You can find these, in fact, without finding the matrix of $T$.

Comment: Why are those the eigenvectors?

Comment: That's the definition of an eigenvector, where the $A$'s are your "vectors".

Answer (score 2):

The transformation $T$ maps from the space $\mathbb R^{2\times 2}$ to itself, meaning it maps a $4$ dimensional space to a $4$ dimensional space.

This means the matrix will be a $4\times 4$ matrix. Think about where the transformation $T$ maps the **basis** of the space $\mathbb R^{2\times 2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Think at $A$ as an element of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^4$:
$$
A=\begin {bmatrix}
a&b\\c&d
\end{bmatrix}=
a\begin {bmatrix}
1&0\\0&0
\end{bmatrix}
+
b\begin {bmatrix}
0&1\\0&0
\end{bmatrix}+
c\begin {bmatrix}
0&0\\1&0
\end{bmatrix}
+
d\begin {bmatrix}
0&0\\0&1
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin {bmatrix}
a\\b\\c\\d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where the matrices at the RHS are the canonical basis for $M_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Now your transformation is:
$$
T(A)=T\begin {bmatrix}
a\\b\\c\\d
\end{bmatrix}=\begin {bmatrix}
a\\c\\b\\d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
can you see the $4\times4$ matrix that represent this transformation?

Answer (score 1):

Since $(A^T)^T = A$, you have $T^2 = I$.  Therefore the only eigenvalues are $\pm 1$.  Eigenvectors for $+1$ are symmetric matrices, those for $-1$ are antisymmetric matrices.

Comment: Doesn't $I$ have only one eigenvalue equal to 1?

Comment: If $T$ has eigenvalue $\lambda$, $T^2 - I$ has eigenvalue $\lambda^2 - 1$.  So you must have $\lambda^2 -1 = 0$, which has solutions $\pm 1$.